# Push a ROM to Galaxy S3 (d2att) while in TWRP/CWM?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking, twrp

My friend has royally buggered up his phone and we can't get a file onto the phone in order to reflash the ROM. We are able to get into the recovery (either TWRP or CWM) and reflash the recovery via Odin- but not able to get anything to onto the phone to flash!

CWM doesn't seem to have an `adb sideload` option on version 6.0.1.2 and adb wouldn't recognize the device in TWRP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do a **nandroid backup** to save the current state of the phone.

Get a ROM that can be flashed via recovery (usually .zip, not .img or .tar.img), then just execute:

```
adb shell mount /sdcard
adb push <romname.zip> /sdcard
```

If the first option to mount the sdcard fails, you can manually mount if from recovery. Also sdcard path might vary from ROM or recovery.

Once the ROM is uploaded to the phone, you can then use the recovery option to install it.

If you're comming from a different ROM, be sure to wipe `/system`, `/data` and `/cache`.

Comment: I wasn't able to detect the phone via `adb devices`, so those commands unfortunately didn't work. I did however solve it by reinstalling my adb drivers specifically for Windows 8 64-bit.